# cookies keep coming back even if i set it to delete

Tags: php

Ok i use this code to set cookies

```
setcookie("search", "active", time()+3600);
```

and i use this to delete cookies

```
setcookie("search", "active", time()-3600);
```

and i use this to check and retrieve cookies

```
<?
  if (isset($_COOKIE["search"]))
  {
      if ($_COOKIE["search"] === "active")
      {
          echo "cookies active"."<br/>";
          echo $_COOKIE["search"];
      }
      else
      {
          echo "cookies is not active";
      }
  }
  else
  {
      echo "no cookies";
  }
?>
```

but the set cookies is keep coming back again and again even if i deleted it using the method the i specify above when i refresh the page.

Comment: the cookie will only be gone on the next reqeust...

Comment: Try a different timestamp like `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am not sure why you get this error but have seen this before

Example : Calling

```
setcookie ( "user", "Alex Porter", time () + 3600 );
setcookie ( "search", "active", time () + 3600 );

var_dump($_COOKIE);

setcookie ( "search", "", time () - 3600 );
```

Only Outputs

```
array(1) {
    ["user"]=>
    string(11) "Alex Porter"
}
```

Expected Result

```
array(2) {
    ["user"]=>
    string(11) "Alex Porter"
    ["search"]=>
    string(6) "active"
}
```

Conclusion

I think you would stick to only one cookie or just remove all the cookies at once

Try

Note* Make sure `setcookie` is always on top of the page and no output is before it

```
setcookie ( "search", "active", time () + 3600 );  
//setcookie ( "search", "", time () - 3600 );  // uncomment when you want to remove cookie
if (isset ( $_COOKIE ["search"] )) {
    if ($_COOKIE ["search"] === "active") {
        echo "cookies active" . "<br/>";
        echo $_COOKIE ["search"];
    } else {
        echo "cookies is not active";
    }
} else {
    echo "no cookies";
}
```

Comment: there is some mistake on my post this one "setcookie ( "user", "Alex Porter", time () + 3600 );" should be this one setcookie ( "search", "active", time () + 3600 );". I am not trying to pui 2 data on one cookie, all i need is to delete that cookie and it should not keep coming back as what im stuck on that right now.

Comment: its because you are setting cookies when you refresh .. use 2 different pages has your demo

Answer (score 1):

Deleting a cookie in PHP does not affect the $_COOKIE super global, as this array is populated before your script runs. It should however no longer be present in $_COOKIE when you load the next page.